# Pointing 1and1 web site to other person's 1and1 hosted site

Tags: web-hosting

I have some 1and1.co.uk webspace and a handful of domains.

This is grand and works fine.

My friend's wife just started a personal training business and wants a small website.

He has written a basic html site, and has a couple domains reserved with 1and1 ready.

He just wants to point these domains to (ideally a folder within) my webspace.

I expect to have to have a redirect on my main site to redirect his stuff to the subfolder, but we can't even do that.

Has anyone else managed this?

I thought it would just be a case of finding the IP address and my friend entering this in, but this throws a 404 error.

Worst thing is, I used to do this kind of thing in my last job, but I thing XBox gaming has knocked all of that knowledge out of my brain. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not much interest in this, but I have recently moved my domains away from 1&1 and in doing so answered my own question!

If you follow this process, it works - it will give you the names of the DNS servers to provide to your new company and the domains work on 1&1 as if you had bought with them!
http://faq.1and1.co.uk/domains/domain_xfers/dns_transfer/4.html

Couple things that worried me at the time were:

1. It said the Mail Server didn't exist with my new company - this was fine and 1&1 took control of them automatically.
2. There was a load of bumf at the bottom going on about how it was a special deal. I wondered if this meant they were going to charge me but they didn't. :)

Hope that helps someone else!

~ Frosty